# Django-allauth How to Ban Certain Users?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth for my Django web app. How can I ban certain users from logging in or restrict certain actions after they log in for a period of time?

Should I just deactivate their accounts outright? What are some good solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally for django authentication you would set the user object's is_active attribute to False and the user wouldn't be able to log in (into django admin for example). But you're using allauth, so by simply setting the is_staff attribute would be enough to block them from entering django admin for example.

Now, if you're implementing another type of frontend dashboard or need to set rules to how a user logs in, I'd say for you to use **AccessMixins** if you're using CBVs or **decorators** if you're using FBV. Specially the *UserPassesTest mixin* and *user_passes_test* decorator. With them you can check if a user comply to a certain rule and then allow them to log in or not. Check the docs [here](http://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html#userpassestestmixin).